# Bootstrap Modal showing in chrome and chrome inspector DevTools but on real Iphone doesn't toggle or show

Tags: jquery, css, iphone, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am creating this test site where I haven't yet separated all css or javascript. I've read **`Bootstrap`** documentation and followed the Getting Started instructions to incorporate a simple Modal Component *(which will have a contact form in it with php)* when clicking the button "04 - get in touch". This modal does appear on Chrome and using the `DevTools Chrome inspector` to verify the responsive version. **But when using my `iPhone` to test, it doesn't toggle the modal.**

The [link is this.](http://indigocreative.mx/Version-04/fullPage.js-master/examples/backgrounds-fixed.html)

I've tried using a simple button, and overriding the modal's "position" property in the css but still doesn't toggle on the iphone. Also overriding the z-index but still not working just on mobile.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="contactModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="contactModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The button:

```
<li id="left">
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactModal"> 04 get in touch</a>
</li>
```